# In an environment with multiple coroutines, is it sane to implement priorities?

Tags: multithreading, lua, coroutine

I'm reading some Lua books and I'm thinking of migrating some legacy (and badly written) C code to a mix of Lua and C.

However, this legacy code uses threads to handle some critical tasks (basically audio/video streaming) while there are simple tasks that also needs some attention (user interface). From what I've read, Lua doesn't support threads directly and it promotes the use of coroutines.

Is it sane to migrate to a coroutine-based environment in a situation like this? In my mind, I can visualize a dispatcher that would always try to resume the high priority coroutines first between each attempt to resume a least important one. As I don't have experience in this subject, I'm asking it here.

**EDIT**

More details were asked by Nicol Bolas.

This is a real time application. I cannot afford to have big delays to handle some events, like a new video frame ready to be processed. The previous C program used threads and callbacks to do this. In the occurrence of a new frame, for example, a callback was called and the data would be prepared for processing (the callback as a producer and the video thread as a consume).

I do not yet have thought about what to do with the callbacks (maybe I'll keep them with C and use some mutexes to update the data for the Lua code), but my doubt is if this kind of setup, using the mentioned tools, are appropriate for this kind of problem and if someone has some examples or stories and would want to share that.

Comment: Without seeing the code, or knowing something more about the specific circumstances, it's very difficult to answer this question with any degree of certainty.

Comment: There is no code yet. I'm asking for opinions if coroutines are worth it for this type of application. It's a real time application (streaming). It's coroutines. Do they get along well?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't try this. The game is to create an appropriate scheduler, and to ensure that none of your routines take too much time before they yield.

How difficult this will be depends on your code, but the scheduler is likely to be pretty simple -- via priorities or simple timers (if last time important_routine was run is > N ms, then run important_routine).

You have some advantages with yield, it certainly makes synchronization easy.

Simply put, you should proof it out and see if it's effective enough for you. Play with it a bit and you should know reasonably quickly if this will actually work out for you or not, from the sounds of it, your scheduler is likely not really sophisticated. There's no reason to make it a general purpose one, keep it simple and dedicated to the tasks you're doing, then you round robin the "generic ones", or pull some random scheduler out of an operating systems text book.

Answer (score 0):

You probably *can* do this; as far as I can tell, you main challenge is going to be in deciding what the smallest chunk of time you can give away and how to guarantee that this chunk of time is not exceeded.

For example, let's say your streaming can tolerate delays up to 10ms. It means that your UI operations have to be split into chunks no longer than 10ms. What if you resume your UI coroutine to do search in files and you need to read a file and it turns out to be large and the reading time exceeds 10ms? Your streaming coroutine won't get control until your UI coroutine yields the control back to the scheduler, which then resumes your streaming coroutine. This only means that you need to be very careful in thinking about all the operations that your UI can do and how you can guarantee that all of them will obey time limits you set for them.

In preemptive multi-tasking the scheduler takes care of that (but it has its own disadvantages), but in the case of coroutines, your UI logic needs to handle that. There are lua libraries that have some similar logic (for example copas does something close to what you may need for sockets using timeouts).

Comparing callbacks and coroutines, I'm starting to like coroutines approach more and more. They are probably equivalent in what they can do, but the coroutine-based code is easier to read (and in many cases write) than a callback-based one (strictly in my opinion).